# How to use IF statement inside a built in function

Tags: excel, vba, function, if-statement

im trying to create a VBA built in function where if depending on the requirement, one type of calculation is done. this is what i tried to do but it is not working. anyone has an example of how do this type of function?

```
Public Function FRPV(ratey As Double, ratet0 As Double, maturity As Date, asof As Date, amount As Double, testif As Double)

If testif = 123 Then
    FRPV = ((1 + (ratey / 100) * (maturity - asof) / 360) * amount) / (1 + (ratet0 / 100) * (maturity - asof) / 360)
    
Else
    FRNPV = (((1 + ratey / 200) ^ ((maturity - asof) / 180)) * amount) / (1 + (ratet0 / 100) * (maturity - asof) / 360)
    
End If

End Function
```

Comment: "FRNPV". Always use Option Explicit.

Comment: Referring to a UDF (user-defined function) as a "built-in function" is confusing. Unless you work for the Excel team at Microsoft, you probably aren't able to write any built-in functions. Also, I second the recommendation to always use `Option Explicit`. It isn't a bad idea to do it once and for all by enabling the "Always Require Variable Declarations" in the VBA editor options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is that your return variable is "FRPV", and in the "Else" block you are setting a different value FRNPV.

And declare the return type. Then users of the function will get some idea of what it might return.

Beyond that, declare the testif parameter in the function as a Long, or perhaps a Boolean if you just have a yes/no option. Or maybe an Integer (as you are perhaps looking at the frequency of the coupon payments, 1 =Annual, 2=Semi-Annual, 4 = Quarterly etc).

Testing the value of a double (which has lots of decimal places) against an integer can be fraught with problems.

```
Public Function FRPV(ratey As Double, ratet0 As Double, maturity As Date, asof As 
        Date, amount As Double, freq As Integer, simple as Boolean) as Double

    If simple Then
        FRPV = ((1 + (ratey / 100) * (maturity - asof) / 360) * amount) / (1 + (ratet0 
               / 100) * (maturity - asof) / 360)
    Else 'Compound
        FRPV = (((1 + ratey / (freq *100)) ^ (freq * (maturity - asof) / 360)) * amount) / (1 + 
              (ratet0 / 100) * (maturity - asof) / 360) 
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: When you set the "Require Variable Declaration" CheckBox in VB-Editor -> Tools -> Options, it will automatically add "Option Explicit" to all new modules. It will avoid making errors like this.